# can i remove the action's script restriction in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

i'm working in a project and i'm using Zend, but there is something i don't like, i need to have a phtml file, with the same name of the action, in a folder with the same name of the controler, if i don't, Zend will throw an exception, i would like to choose the location myself, cuz i have to make a bunch of folder in my modules, maybe somthing more simple, but i don't know if it is possible, maybe zend is strict with this.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an "individual view script" for an Action you can use:

```
$this->renderScript('path/to/myviewscript.phtml');
```

Comment: or `$this->render('name')` will render `name.phtml` from the view directory ;)

Comment: it was not exactly what i was looking for, but get me in the right way, thanks a lot